# Publish data to Azure IoT Hub with MQTT

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am having a device which able to publish data to any MQTT broker. I am trying to publish data to Azure IoT Hub with this device as client.

Machine is having the data as follows,

1. Device/Topic1/Param1
2. Device/Topic1/Param2
3. Device/Topic1/Param3
4. Device/Topic2/Param1
5. Device/Topic2/Param2 and so on around 50 parameters from 7 different topics.

How can send all those parameters to Azure IoT Hub with MQTT? In IoT Hub I able to create device but it gives only one topic per device. Is there any other feasibility?

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for Azure IoTHub's MQTT support?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Comment: Yes. I have seen this document. I don't know how to accommodate the multiple topics from machine IoT Hub devices.

Comment: @SathishkumarC the Azure IoT Hub is not a generic MQTT broker, this capability has only Azure IoT Edge MQTT broker, see more details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11

Comment: Roman please can you convert your comment to the answer?